# jCarouselLite autoscroll not show one enty

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using jCarouselLite for showing important event in show page, but when I add only single event it does not show(while more than one event display on show page and auto scroll work properly)..

Here is my code:-

```
       .scroll{:style=>"margin:5px 0 0 10px;"}
         -if @individual.important_events.present?
           %ul
             -@individual.important_events.each do |event|
               %li
                 = link_to event.title, important_events_path
                 %br
                 = event.date
```

And script is:-

```
:javascript     
  $(function() {
    $(".scroll").jCarouselLite({
      auto: 800,
      speed: 1000,
      vertical: true,
      circular: true
    });
  });
```

How can I show single entry of event in my show page??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
   .scroll{:style=>"margin:5px 0 0 10px;"}
      %ul
        -@individual.important_events.each do |event|
          %li
            = link_to event.title, important_events_path(event)
            %br
            = event.date
```